Automatically running a window on raspbian bookworm on (desktop) startup (with auto-login)
I run a few Raspberry Pi / Bookworm systems that preform various services for the home network, including DNS, 3d print service management and so on.  Also, I have a few "clocks" around the place, running on RPi/Bookworm accessing an internal site via chromium.
On all these systems, I have set up .xsession to run chromium to access the appropriate page on an internal web server (happens to also be RPi).  But today, I installed a brand new RPi 4B and updated the software (apt update && apt -y upgrade), created .xsession, ran raspi-config to ensure auto desktop start and login and son on.
On this system, it seems that .xsession is being ignored.  Looking around, I have found a number of people have suggestions that don't help me (usually creating some autostart file or autostart directory under ~/.config or ~/.autostart or any number of other places... none of which seem to be the right answer for this system.
Lookind a bit more deaply, I found that /etc/alternatives/x-window-manager points to openbox:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  16 Feb  9  2023 x-window-manager -> /usr/bin/openbox

So I  created ~/.config/openbox/autostart with the following content:
/usr/local/startClock &

... and I can confirm that this script does NOT seem to be running at startup.  (Firstt command is "touch /tmp/it-is-running" - and that file never appears.  If I ssh into the system and set DISPLAY variable and run /usr/local/startClock, then the process runs without error.  (I do have the problem that Chromium doesn't like this http site but there's another open quesion on that.)
Any tips on what I should try next?
/etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

openbox --version:
Openbox 3.6.1
Copyright (c) 2004   Mikael Magnusson
Copyright (c) 2002   Dana Jansens

